# Extract the text within each single quote using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing two columns, the first column is month, and the second column is all the firms that applied for a tax compensation in this month. Each entry in this column looks like this

```
['firm A','firm B',...]
```

I want to extract the names of the first three firms that submit the application for each month, and create three new columns for the name extractions, each firm in one column.

I tried commands like

```
gsub("^'(.*)'.*", "\\", df)
```

but it didn't work properly

Answer (score 3):

Using `base R`

```
cbind(df[1], read.csv(text = gsub("[]'[]", "",
  df$tax_compensation), header = FALSE, col.names = paste0("firm_", 1:4)))
```

-output

```
 month firm_1 firm_2 firm_3 firm_4
1   Jan firm A firm B firm C firm D
2   Feb firm B firm C firm A firm D
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(month = c("Jan", "Feb"), 
tax_compensation = c("['firm A','firm B','firm C','firm D']", 
"['firm B','firm C','firm A','firm D']")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

One potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(month = c("Jan", "Feb"),
                 tax_compensation = c("['firm A','firm B','firm C','firm D']",
                                      "['firm A','firm B','firm C','firm D']"))
df
#>   month                      tax_compensation
#> 1   Jan ['firm A','firm B','firm C','firm D']
#> 2   Feb ['firm A','firm B','firm C','firm D']

df %>%
  mutate(tax_compensation = gsub("[^']+('[^']+','[^']+','[^']+').*", "\\1", tax_compensation)) %>%
  separate(col = tax_compensation, into = c("first_firm", "second_firm", "third_firm"), sep = ",")
#>   month first_firm second_firm third_firm
#> 1   Jan   'firm A'    'firm B'   'firm C'
#> 2   Feb   'firm A'    'firm B'   'firm C'
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Extending, as a generic solution, to what Jared suggested, so that if you want to create more than three columns, you should be able to do it (but if you want to restrict to first three, just replace 10 with 3 in `paste0("firm_", 1:10)` as `paste0("firm_", 1:3)` that returns what you wanted):

```
 df %>%
  mutate(tax_compensation = str_remove_all(tax_compensation, "[^[:alnum:]|\\s|,]")) %>%
  separate(col = tax_compensation, into = paste0("firm_", 1:10), sep = ",", fill = "right") %>%
  select(month, where(~ any(!is.na(.))))
```

should return you:

```
  month firm_1 firm_2 firm_3 firm_4
1   Jan firm A firm B firm C firm D
2   Feb firm A firm B firm C firm D
```

here, you can provide any range, depending upon the number of firms there could, in the code `paste0("firm_", 1:10)` and `select(month, where(~ any(!is.na(.))))` will filter out the columns that will contain only NAs.

As asked by Hasan, here is an explanation:

The `str_remove_all()` function was used to remove all non-alphanumeric characters (as we can see that there are, quotes and commas) from the tax_compensation column.

To do so, a regular expression pattern "[^[:alnum:]|\s|,]" was used. Basically, [^[:alnum:]] matches any character that is not a letter or a digit (non-alphanumeric).

Here, `|` is the logical `OR` operator.

And, `\\s` will match any whitespace characters (e.g. a white space, a tab such as \t, or a newline such as \n characters). `,` simply matches a comma.

Therefore, together, this regular expression will search and match any characters that are not a letter, a digit, a white space or a comma, and the `str_remove_all()` function will then replace these characters with an empty string.

This will result in a clean version of `tax_compensation` column and pass to next operator through chaining operation of `tidyverse` and `dplyr`.

Let me know if that helps..

Comment: Thanks, it works quite well, can you explain a little bit on the green part in the second line? I tried many expressions but none worked as clean as this one.

Comment: thanks... updated my answer with explanation.. hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>% 
  # extract all firm IDs from strings:
  mutate(tax_compensation = str_extract_all(tax_compensation, "(?<=')[^']+[A-Z](?=')")) %>% 
  # cast the list members wider into columns:
  unnest_wider(tax_compensation) %>%
  # use column names as you see fit:
  rename_with(~str_replace(., "(\\.){3}", "firm_"), matches("\\d$"))
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  month firm_1 firm_2 firm_3 firm_4
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Jan   firm A firm B firm C firm D
2 Feb   firm B firm C firm A firm D
```

Note on regex:

- `(?<=')`: positive look-behind to assert that match must be preceded by `'`
- `[^']+[A-Z]`: any string that does not contain a `'` and that ends in upper-case letter
- `(?=')`: positive look-ahead to assert that the match must be followed by `'`

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(month = c("Jan", "Feb"),
                 tax_compensation = c("['firm A','firm B','firm C','firm D']",
                                      "['firm B','firm C','firm A','firm D']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For long format you can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(month = c("Jan", "Feb"),
                 tax_compensation = c("['firm A','firm B','firm C','firm D']",
                                      "['firm A','firm B','firm C','firm D']"))

df |> 
  separate_rows(tax_compensation, sep = ",") |> 
  mutate(across(tax_compensation, ~ str_remove_all(.x, "[^A-Z]"))) |> 
  group_by(month) |> 
  slice_head(n = 3)

# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   month [2]
  month tax_compensation
  <chr> <chr>           
1 Feb   A               
2 Feb   B               
3 Feb   C               
4 Jan   A               
5 Jan   B               
6 Jan   C
```